# jpa:repositories / @EnableJpaRepositories vs @Repository - spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Does using the `@EnableJpaRepositories` or `jpa:repositories` (on the xml) gives the developer not to use `@Repository` tag of Spring? As I look on the example guidelines of Spring most of their examples is that they do not use the @Repository tag anymore on their interfaces that extends JpaRepository or CrudRepository interface of Spring Data.

I tried to use them together but Intellij warns me that it can not autowired my repository because there is more than one bean. I tried to remove the jpa:repositories on my xml file but the an error appeared that the application can not create a bean for my entity manager.

Answer (score 4):

These are two different things. @Repository annotation is much older than Spring Data and is used to tell Spring to translate all exceptions thrown by @Repository annotated components to DataAccessException (more to read here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html)

In SpringData you have @EnableJpaRepositories + entire underlying scanning and repository bean generation mechanism and there is no need to mark your repository interfaces (or custom classes) with @Repository.

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring Data Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.namespace) is IMHO not entirely clear about this.
In chapter 3.1.1 it says:

> Using the repositories element looks up Spring Data repositories as described in “Creating Repository Instances”. Beyond that, it activates persistence exception translation for all beans annotated with @Repository, to let exceptions being thrown by the JPA persistence providers be converted into Spring’s DataAccessException hierarchy.

To me this sounds like you would still need to add @Repository explicitly in order to activate persistance exception translation.